# react / jest >> mock an imported (default) function from npm package

Tags: reactjs, import, promise, jestjs, mocking

I'm trying to mock "readXlsxFile" function coming from "read-excel-file" npm package.
My mistake is probably located at `jest.spyOn(readXlsxFile, "default")`
I already tryed multiple async / await combinations as well as method "act" from react testing-library but keep getting this error message meaning I'm definately doing it bad

also please take note that my mock should return a Promise

import.tsx

```
import readXlsxFile, { Row } from "read-excel-file";
​
const Import: NextPageWithLayout = () => {
​
const handleFileSubmit: FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement> = async (e): Promise<void> => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (file) {
        const readFile: Row[] = await readXlsxFile(file);
        // [...]
        }
    }
}
```

import.test.js

```
import { render, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import readXlsxFile from "read-excel-file";
import Import from "./import";
​
const xlsx = [
    ["Poste", "Designation", "Secteur", "Îlot", "Etat", "Arrêts planifiés/jour"],
    ["101003", "OOF_[OOF]", "[OOF]", "[OOF]", "OFF", 0],
  ];
​
test("check file (form submit)", () => {
    // rendering component
    const component = render(<Import />);
    // need to push a fake file into this input at first (it's working fine in a previous test)
    // this will enable form submit button & update some state variables
    fireEvent.change(component.getByTestId("fileInput"), {
      target: {
        files: [new File([new Blob([JSON.stringify([{ a: "b" }])])], "test")],
      },
    });
    // the problem is here
    const mock = jest.spyOn(readXlsxFile, "default").mockImplementation(() => {
      return Promise.resolve(xlsx);
    });
    // submit form which call handleFileSubmit
    fireEvent.submit(component.getByTestId("ImportForm"));
    mock.mockRestore();
});
```

terminal output

```
/mnt/DATA/www/frontend/node_modules/read-excel-file/commonjs/read/unpackXlsxFileBrowser.js:16
   return file.arrayBuffer().then(function (fileBuffer) {
               ^

 TypeError: file.arrayBuffer is not a function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this kind of mock:

```js
const xlsx = [
    ["Poste", "Designation", "Secteur", "Îlot", "Etat", "Arrêts planifiés/jour"],
    ["101003", "OOF_[OOF]", "[OOF]", "[OOF]", "OFF", 0],
  ];

const mockReadExcelFile = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(xlsx);
jest.mock('read-excel-file', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: () => mockReadExcelFile(),
}));

test(...
```

you can change the mocked implementation in tests if you need to with:

```js
mockReadExcelFile.mockResolvedValue(some other value);
```

Comment: I also add to remove `import readXlsxFile from "read-excel-file";` from import.test.js to make this mock works.

but it's working, thanks a lot !